# A question concerning linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

(Multiple options could be correct!)

> **Q.** Let $A$ be a $4\times 4$ matrix over $\mathbb R$ such that
> $\rho(A)=2$, and $A^3=A^2\ne O$. Suppose that $A$ is not diagonalizable.
> Then
>
> (a) One of the Jordan blocks of the Jordan Canonical form of $A$ is
> $\pmatrix{ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0}.$
>
> (b) $A^2=A\ne O.$
>
> (c) $\exists$ a vector $v$ such that $A^2v=O.$
>
> (d) The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $x^4-x^3.$

Here, $\rho(A)$ means *the rank of* $A,$ and $O$ denotes *the zero matrix of order* $4$. **My attempt:**

If $f(x)=x^3-x^2=x^2(x-1),$ then $f(A)=O.$ So, the minimal polynomial of $A, m(x)$ (say), must divide $f(x).$ Since $A$ is not diagonalizable, the only possible choice for $m(x)$ is $x^2(x-1).$ This imples that there is a Jordan block of size $2$ in the Jordan Canonical form of $A$ corresponding to the eigen value $0$ of $A$. Therefore, option (a) is correct.

If $A^2=A\ne O$ were true, that would mean that the matrix $A$ is idempotent, hence diagonalizable. However, it is not so. Thus, we see that option (b) is false. (right?)

$A^2v=O$ represents a homogeneous system of linear equations. As such, it is always consistent. So, option (c) is correct! (right?)

Since $m(x)\mid c(x),$ the characteristic polynomial of $A.$ There are two possible choices for $c(x)$, viz., $x^3(x-1)$ and    $x^2(x-1)^2.$ In addition, the geometric multiplicity of the eigen value $0, \gamma(0)$ (say), equals the nullity of $A-0I_4,$ that is: $\gamma(0)=\eta(A-0I_4)=\eta(A)=4-\rho(A)=4-2=2.$ But, $A$ is not diagonalizable. Therefore, the algebraic multiplicity of the eigen value $0$, $\alpha(0)$ (say), must not equal $\gamma(0).$ Now, we find that among the two feasible choices for $c(x),$ only the former one, i.e, $c(x)=x^3(x-1)=x^4-x^3,$ satisfies this condition. Because $\alpha(0)=3\ne 2=\gamma(0)$ in this case. Hence, option (d) is correct as well. (right?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Option (a): I know you didn’t ask, but **correct**! The minimal polynomial must divide $x^2(x - 1)$, and cannot be square-free (otherwise it’s diagonalisable). So yes, the minimal polynomial must be $x^2(x - 1)$. The power of $x$ represents the largest Jordan block corresponding to eigenvalue $0$, so a $\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$ block must occur in the JNF.

Option (b): **Correct**! Alternatively, if $A^2 = A$, then the minimal polynomial must divide $x^2 - x = x(x - 1)$, which would contradict $x^3 - x^2$ being the minimal polynomial.

Option (c): **Technically correct**! Your answer perfectly suits the question as written, but I’m sure the intention behind the question was to specify $v \neq 0$. A homogeneous system may only have the $0$ solution, so eliminating $v = 0$ would make your answer invalid. In this particular case, however, there will be a non-trivial solution to $A^2v = 0$, simply because $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. We can even choose $v \neq 0$ and $Av \neq 0$ (though the first condition is redundant), by choosing a generalised eigenvector of index $2$. So, your answer is $100\%$ correct, but I think whomever wrote the question was hoping for more, and just wrote the question badly.

Option (d): **Incorrect**! Yes, there are two possibilities of characteristic polynomials, and both are possible. For example, consider the following JNF matrices:
$$J_1 = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1}, \qquad J_2 = \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1}.$$
The characteristic polynomials are, respectively, $x^3(x - 1)$ and $x^2(x - 1)^2$. The geometric multiplicities of $\lambda = 0$ of these matrices are $2$ and $1$ respectively, while their algebraic multiplicities are $3$ and $2$ respectively. Neither are diagonalisable (which can be seen by the $2 \times 2$ Jordan block in each of them).

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, the rank is assumed to be $2$. This eliminates $J_2$, and anything similar to it, from being $A$. Thus, the answer given in the question is indeed **correct**.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir, for giving explanations for all the options. However, I am having a doubt regarding the explanation of option (d). From what I know, for a given matrix $A$ the geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is defined as $\gamma(\lambda)=\eta(A-\lambda I)$. As such, $\gamma(\lambda)$ is fixed. How come $\lambda=0$ is allowed to have two different geometric multiplicities in this case? Also, the insight concerning option (c) is wonderful. Generalized eigenvectors didn't even cross my mind. You made a typo "$Av^2=0$" while explaining option (c). Please rectify it!

Comment: @Usual_Learner I confess, I don’t understand your issue with $(d)$, either in the comment or in the original question. The geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ is indeed the null space of $A - \lambda I$. It’s not that one matrix can have two such eigenspaces, it’s that the information in the question is not sufficient to tell whether the geometric multiplicity of $0$ is $1$ or $2$. Only one is possible at a time, but either one could be right. I gave two examples of possible matrices satisfying the conditions on $A$, but with the two different possible characteristic polynomials.

Comment: Sir, please note that the rank of $A$ is given. So, $\gamma(0)=\eta(A)=4-\rho(A)=2.$

Comment: @Usual_Learner Oh! I missed that! Part of that is that I've never seen $\rho$ represent the rank like that before (nor the other Greek letters represent things like null space or geometric multiplicity). In that case, yes, you are correct. My apologies.

Comment: To be picky, there are two choices for the minimal polynomial, namely $x^2(x-1)$ or $x^2$. However, the latter would contradict $A^2\ne O$.

Comment: @egreg Right, sir. To be honest, I didn't really consider it! Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @TheoBendit Not an issue, sir. These kinds of symbols are rather common in my nation. I was also taught this way. So, I am sort of used to using these in this context. Thanks...